# How to generate serial number in a query?

Tags: database, postgresql

We're using PostgreSQL v8.2.3.

How do I generate serial number in the query output?  I want to display serial number for each row returned by the query.

Example: `SELECT employeeid, name FROM employee`

I expect to generate and display serial number against each row starting from one.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You have two options.

Either upgrade to PostgreSQL v8.4 and use the `row_number()` function:

```
SELECT row_number() over (ORDER BY something) as num_by_something, *
FROM table
ORDER BY something;
```

Or jump through some hoops as described in [Simulating Row Number in PostgreSQL Pre 8.4](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/index.php?/archives/79-Simulating-Row-Number-in-PostgreSQL-Pre-8.4.html).

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT row_number() over (order by employeeid) as serial_number,
       employeeid,
       name
FROM employee
```

If you want to assign the numbers according to the sorting of the name, change the order by in the `over` clause

Comment: But `row_number()` *window function* is not available in v8.2.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that you are using 8.2, but I would strongly recommend to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a row number added to your **current** *unordered* select results, then you don't really want to `order` them - that will (obviously) change the sequence of those unordered rows.

In that case, just pass a constant to `order by`:

```
    SELECT row_number() over (order by 1) as serial_number,
           employeeid,
           name
    FROM employee
```

The most likely use case would be where the default table order is using the order of row insertions, and you want to preserve that (eg, perhaps someone gave you a .csv from Excel that implicitly has row numbers on the left (*outside the sheet*) and is expecting to see the rows in the same order as they were entered there. (...something I just had to deal with :- )

Then, you can use that to preserve the unordered row sequence by
`INSERT INTO` *`<new table with sequence column> <above select query>`*`;`

It may also be useful during a screen share or code hackathon to have a quick way to reference specific rows.