# Query result with added column number auto incremented dynamically

Tags: sql, postgresql

How do I add extra column to get row number added to my query result and increment dynamically with query resulted rows.

I have tried using [How to generate serial number in a query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731973/how-to-generate-serial-number-in-a-query)

```
select row_number() over (order by e_id) as Sr.No,name,(select role_name from role where r_e_fid = e_id),year from emloyee 
group by e_id,name,year 
order by role_name desc, year asc
```

But the result is like below

```
Sr.No   name   role_name     year 
  4     Vasim  DBA           2010
  2     Khasi  Develper      2010
  5     Raj    FullStack     2012
  1     Ghani  FullStack     2012
  3     Shanu  FullStack     2013
```

Sr.No is getting scuffled.

Comment: The question you linked to has good answers. What code did you try, that gave you „the ID value instead Serial Number“ ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate serial number in a query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731973/how-to-generate-serial-number-in-a-query)

Comment: I have updated my query, please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the sequence number to be the same as the result set, use the same order by keys.  In fact, you can order by the column itself!

```
select row_number() over (order by e.name_desc, e.year asc) as sr_no, 
       e.name,
       (select r.role_name from role r where r.r_e_fid = e.e_id),
       year
from emloyee e
group by e.e_id, e.name, e.year 
order by sr_no;
```

Note that I added table aliases and qualified the column references.  This is a best practice so queries are understandable, maintainable, and do what you really intend.

Also, if `e_id` is the primary key in `employee`, then you can just use `group by e.e_id`.

Comment: This is what exactly I am looking for, I have posted my answer and updated my quetion as I haven't mention the result has to be sorted by subquery column. UPVOTED cheers.

Comment: @Raj . . . If this is exactly what you are looking form why haven't you accepted it?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the linked question, use a query like this:

```
SELECT row_number() over (ORDER BY name) as Sr_No, *
FROM std
where name like '%J%'
ORDER BY Sr_No;
```

The key is using `row_number()`. It's a auto identity value not coming from table fields itself.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the answer given by @[Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff)

```
select row_number() over (order by (select r.role_name from role r where r.r_e_fid = e.e_id) desc, e.year asc) as Sr.No,e.name,(select rs.role_name from role rs where rs.r_e_fid = e.e_id),e.year from emloyee e
group by e.e_id,e.name,e.year 
order Sr.No
```

Now the query is working pretty fine with sub query as well.